# Apple TV can't always be detected by Mac & iPhone

Tags: appletv

I have both a Mac and iPhone: the AirPlay icon to stream video and music to AppleTV randomly appears and disappears on both of them.

I think it is a network issue, but I don't know how to solve it, since it might work perfectly one day and the next no device can find the AppleTV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I can say that AirPlay regularly works on all my devices. Rarely the rebooting is needed, usually it is avaulable. I don't know why, probably software updates to iOS 6.1 or latest version of Lyon. Or probably, because I've restarted my modem few times.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. My Mac, iPhone, or iPad wouldn't connect because the icon disappears at random intervals.

You can try plugging in an Ethernet cable, however this doesn't seem to permanently fix the problem.

What I did was get a new router that supports dual band (2.4 GHz and 5 GHz). The iPhone uses 2.4 GHz and my Mac and AppleTV use 5 GHz. There was less traffic that way (because of splitting the bands over different devices) through the router and the AppleTV is always detected. This forced the AirPlay option to always appear on my devices.

You can check my question and other possible answers here [AirPlay option disappeared?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59428/airplay-option-disappeared)

Comment: Sorry for late delay. I did some more testing and the iPad actually always work, it is just the Macbook Air that has this issue. When I restart it, it always work right after the reboot. Instead after sleep, it never works.

Comment: Not sure why. I solved my problem by getting a new router.